# How to edit JSON API response

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I am using [this api](http://manage.directi.com/kb/answer/764)

```
https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=0&api-key=key&domain-name=domain1&domain-name=domain2&tlds=com&tlds=net
```

When I pass some parameters in this api it gives me output in this format

```
{
"apple.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"},
"microsoft.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"apple.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"microsoft.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.org":{"status":"unknown"}
}
```

This Json format is very strange for me.. So I want to change Json format like this

```
[{
        "name": "apple.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.com",
        "status": "available",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "apple.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    }]
```

I am using this code for using API.

```
 protected string GET(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are reading the data from a file and sending back as a string, there are 2 options, create a class which represent the `{
        "name": "apple.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    }` and after reading create a list of objects and send that list, or easier solution is change the data in the file to represented format

Comment: If you don't mind can you write full code ...How can we do?? because I am trying this but I am unable to write exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to transform the JSON from one format into another, if that's what you really want to do.  Here is a method which will do that:

```
public static string TransformJson(string originalJson)
{
    return new JArray(
        JObject.Parse(originalJson).Properties().Select(jp => 
        {
            var jo = new JObject((JObject)jp.Value);
            jo.AddFirst(new JProperty("name", jp.Name));
            return jo;
        })
    ).ToString();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BoU8W5

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble using your GET method to connect to the api. It always return ConnectFailure...

Anyway, the api is actually returning a dictionary type json. So you must create a class and deserialize the json response accordingly.

```
    public class UrlObject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string classkey { get; set; }
    }

//string jsonResponse = GET("https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=0&api-key=key&domain-name=domain1&domain-name=domain2&tlds=com&tlds=net");
string jsonResponse = "{\"apple.com\":{\"status\":\"regthroughothers\",\"classkey\":\"domcno\"},\"asdfgqwx.com\":{\"status\":\"available\",\"classkey\":\"domcno\"},\"microsoft.org\":{\"status\":\"unknown\"},\"apple.org\":{\"status\":\"unknown\"},\"microsoft.com\":{\"status\":\"regthroughothers\",\"classkey\":\"domcno\"},\"asdfgqwx.org\":{\"status\":\"unknown\"}}";

Dictionary<string, UrlObject> urlDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, UrlObject>>(jsonResponse);
```

Notice that the json deserialization is successful, now you can access the values. As I don't see the point of converting the json format into another I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have control over the server, or the server exposes an API to do so, you cannot alter the response that the server returns.

If you want a different object model, e.g. an array of objects instead of a dictionary of objects, as outlined in your question, then you'll need to write some code to map from the APIs model to the model you want to actually use within your application/library.